# Python: concurrently pending on async coroutine and synchronous function

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I'd like to establish an SSH SOCKs tunnel (using `asyncssh`) during the execution of a synchronous function. When the function is done I want to tear down the tunnel and exit.

Apparently some async function has to be *await*ed to keep the tunnel working so the important thing is that `conn.wait_closed()` and the synchronous function are executed concurrently. So I am quite sure that I actually need a second thread.
I first tried some saner things using a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with `run_in_executor` but then ended up with the abysmal multihreaded variant below.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import traceback
from threading import Thread
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

import asyncio, asyncssh, sys

_server="127.0.0.1"
_port=22
_proxy_port=8080


async def run_client():
    conn = await asyncio.wait_for(
        asyncssh.connect(
            _server,
            port=_port,
            options=asyncssh.SSHClientConnectionOptions(client_host_keysign=True),
        ),
        10,
    )

    listener = await conn.forward_socks('127.0.0.1', _proxy_port)
    return conn

async def do_stuff(func):
    try:
        conn = await run_client()
        print("SSH tunnel active")

        def start_loop(loop):
            asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
            try:
                loop.run_forever()
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"worker loop: {e}")

        async def thread_func():
            ret=await func()
            print("Func done - tearing done worker thread and SSH connection")
            conn.close()
            #  asyncio.get_event_loop().stop()
            return ret

        func_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        func_thread = Thread(target=start_loop, args=(func_loop,))
        func_thread.start()
        print("thread started")
        fut = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(thread_func(), func_loop)
        print(f"fut scheduled: {fut}")

        done = await asyncio.gather(asyncio.wrap_future(fut), conn.wait_closed())
        print("wait done")
        for ret in done:
            print(f"ret={ret}")

        # Canceling pending tasks and stopping the loop
        #  asyncio.gather(*asyncio.Task.all_tasks()).cancel()

        print("stopping func_loop")
        func_loop.call_soon_threadsafe(func_loop.stop())
        print("joining func_thread")
        func_thread.join()
        print("joined func_thread")

    except (OSError, asyncssh.Error) as exc:
        sys.exit('SSH connection failed: ' + str(exc))
    except (Exception) as exc:
        sys.exit('Unhandled exception: ' + str(exc))
        traceback.print_exc()


async def just_wait():
    print("starting just_wait")
    input()
    print("ending just_wait")
    return 42

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(do_stuff(just_wait))
```

It actually "works" "correctly" till the end where I get an exception while `join`ing the worker thread. I presume because something I do is not threadsafe.

```
Exception in callback None()
handle: <Handle>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py", line 88, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

To test the code you must have a local SSH server running with key files setup for your user. You may want to change the `_port` variable.

I am looking for the reason of the exception and/or a version of the program that requires less manual intervention in the threading and possibly uses just a single event loop. I don't know how to achieve the latter when I want to `await` the two things (as in the `asyncio.gather` call).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate cause of your error is this line:

```
# incorrect
func_loop.call_soon_threadsafe(func_loop.stop())
```

The intention is to call `func_loop.stop()` in the thread that runs the `func_loop` event loop. But as written, it invokes `func_loop.stop()` **in the current thread** and passes its return value (`None`) to `call_soon_threadsafe` as the function to invoke. This causes `call_soon_threadsafe` to complain that None is not callable. To fix the immediate problem, you should drop the extra parentheses and invoke the method as:

```
# correct
func_loop.call_soon_threadsafe(func_loop.stop)
```

However, the code is definitely over-complicated as written:

- it doesn't make sense to create a new event loop when you are already inside an event loop
- `just_wait` shouldn't be `async def` since it doesn't await anything, so it's clearly not async.
- `sys.exit` takes an integer exit status, not a string. Also, it doesn't make much sense to attempt to print a backtrace *after* the call to `sys.exit`.

To run a non-async function from asyncio, just use `run_in_executor` with the function and pass it the non-async function as-is. You don't need an extra thread nor an extra event loop, `run_in_executor` will take care of the thread and connect it with your current event loop, effectively making the sync function awaitable. For example (untested):

```
async def do_stuff(func):
    conn = await run_client()
    print("SSH tunnel active")
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    ret = await loop.run_in_executor(None, func)
    print(f"ret={ret}")
    conn.close()
    await conn.wait_closed()
    print("wait done")

def just_wait():
    # just_wait is a regular function; it can call blocking code,
    # but it cannot await
    print("starting just_wait")
    input()
    print("ending just_wait")
    return 42

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(do_stuff(just_wait))
```

If you need to await things in `just_wait`, you can make it `async` and use `run_in_executor` for the actual blocking code inside it:

```
async def do_stuff():
    conn = await run_client()
    print("SSH tunnel active")
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    ret = await just_wait()
    print(f"ret={ret}")
    conn.close()
    await conn.wait_closed()
    print("wait done")

async def just_wait():
    # just_wait is an async function, it can await, but
    # must invoke blocking code through run_in_executor
    print("starting just_wait")
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    await loop.run_in_executor(None, input)
    print("ending just_wait")
    return 42

asyncio.run(do_stuff())
```

Comment: Thanks. Both solutions work but is there an easy way to keep `just_wait` async? Maybe by wrapping it before passing it to `run_in_executor`?

Comment: @stefanct If you make `just_wait` async then you don't need to invoke it through `run_in_executor`, you can just `await` it. But then you need to wrap blocking calls inside `just_wait` with `run_in_executor`, e.g. replace `input()` with `await loop.run_in_executor(None, input)`.

Comment: Understood. However, the latter becomes rather complicated if `just_wait` contains various interweaved synchronous and asynchronous function calls. I think that was my initial rationale to make it `async` and handle it independently in its own thread: that would make the whole code less dependent on `just_wait` (i.e. make it easily replaceable/more modular).

Comment: @stefanct Well, the basic contract of an async function is that it doesn't contain blocking calls. (With the exception of those routed through `run_in_executor` which exists exactly for that purpose.) What you propose an "async" function that contains async code, but also occasionally blocks the event loop, and therefore can't be normally awaited, but must be run in _another_ event loop created for the sole purpose of that invocation. That's something you can do, but it runs against the design of asyncio, and you're likely to run into problems down the line. I wouldn't recommend it.